# How to structure an app with many similar views/activities?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

#### Background:

I'm creating an Android app (my second) and I'm not really sure how to structure it.
The section of the app I'm having issues with is basically a sort of simple catalogue; a user clicks a button which opens a layout containing a title (`TextView`) and an image (`ImageView`).

**Image for clarity:**
[image: App structure]

What is the best way to structure this? Since I'm pretty new to Android development, my approach would have been to create an activity for the first view (no.1), create a seperate activity for each of the "Products"-pages, "Products 1", "Products 2" etc. and a third activity for the single item view.

I know how to reuse the "single item"-layout (no.3) but I'm not really sure what the best approach is for no.2.

#### Question:

Should I create six new activities for "Products 1", "Products 2",..,"Products 6" and corresponding layouts for each? Or should I try to keep the number of activities to a minimum?

Any help is highly appriciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app is like a tree-structure app, so three activities/views are enough for your application.

1. Products Category List(Contains Product1, Product2, etc.)
2. Product List(Contains Product1-1, Product1-2, etc.)
3. Product(Contains image for a product)

You should not create an extra activity for every product because it will consume too many system resources.

For coding, you can make a base class since these three activities are similar, and put common elements into the base class.

Comment: This is the path I choose. Thanks for your insight!

Answer (score 0):

If you use listviews the first two screens can be just one activity, with different data passed in to display screen 2. And screen 3 will be common for all, another activity.

If you are planning on keeping the screens as you displayed above, with buttons, then you can just create one layout with button, use it as a row layout within a listview. The activity logic would be such that, depending on data, it would populate one or more rows. With this option too you can do screens 1 and 2 using one activity and one set of layouts.

Answer (score -1):

You make one layout:-

```
1. layout one you can visible(visibility) first 6 textview and other will b gone(visibility).

2. Layout two you can visible(visibility) textview what you want and other will b gone(visibility).

3. Layout three you can visible(visibility) only image view and other will b gone(visibility).
```

note:- change textview value through **setText**.